# Zend Framework Forms, subforms, and decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I currently have a zend framework application with multiple modules. Each module should be using the same [Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript), located in the `default` modules `/views/scripts` folder.

Without any changes, modules by default only look for form decorator viewscripts in their own `/views/scripts` folder located under each module, so to get them to load them from `default` modules folder, I first need to apply this within the form:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts');
$this->setView($view);
```

Within that same form, I create multiple `Zend_Form_SubForm`s, for which I need to apply that same code again. If that isn't enough, I need to apply that path to each individual element in each SubForm as well as the parent form. Additionally, each element has to have its ViewScript defined each time like:

```
$username->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '/formScripts/wizardElement.phtml'))));
```

Now, it all works if I define all of that for each element/subform/form within the same file, but it just seems so much unnecessary work/code.

- Can the process be simplified firstly
  by just having the parent form define
  the `scriptPath` for itself, its
  elements, its subforms, and the
  subforms elements?
- Can new elements created automatically have specific `ViewScripts` defined for them, based on what type of element it is (i.e. input box, checkbox, selectbox, textarea, button etc)?

I am currently extending my form directly from the default `Zend_Form`, I won't have a problem of creating an own abstract form to extend my forms from, but especially with the `scriptPath` problems, I am not entirely sure how I should approach this whole problem.

Applying:

```
$this->setSubFormDecorators(array(
            'Form',
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '/formScripts/wizardSubForm.phtml'))            
));
```

overwrites all the element specific decorators I've applied before it.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried using setElementDecorators for setting the decorator to all the elements added previously at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I didn't get your case in details but I would suggest you create base form, then base form classes for each module then your specific forms extend the respective module form

```
My_Base_Form extends Zend_Form
{
   public function init()
   {
     //if you need to init something for all forms
     parent::init();
   }

   public function _createSelect($name)
   {
      $element=new Zend_Form_Element_Select($name);
      $element->setDecorators(
             //decorators for select
         )
      $element->viewScript='select.phtml';
      return $element;
   }
}

My_Default_Form extends My_Base_Form
{
   public function init()
   {

     //what you do to init dirs for this module
     $view = new Zend_View();
     $view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts');
     $this->setView($view);
     parent::init();
   }

   //called automatically by Zend_Form
   public function loadDefaultDecorators()
   {

       parent::loadDefaultDecorators();
       $this->setDefaultFormDecorators($this);
       $this->setButtonDecorators($this);
   }

}
My_Admin_Form extends My_Base_From{}
```

To not repeat setting element decorators you may create helper methods that do that for you
and put it in the base form class or in the module form class

```
Default_Form_Register extends My_Default_Form
{
     public function init()
     {
         $el=$this->_createSelect($name);
         $el->setLabel('Select');
         $this->addElement($el);
         parent::init();
     }
}
```

you may need to use the same approach for subforms, then put the base classes in your library and you should be ok.

You are will be free to make common changes based on module or element type.